# How to remove some part of a string from every row in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with one of the columns as follows:
`log_df['message']`

```
0      timestamp1678081731027formatversion1webaclidar...
1      timestamp1678081732769formatversion1webaclidar...
2      timestamp1678081732812formatversion1webaclidar...
3      timestamp1678081732890formatversion1webaclidar...
4      timestamp1678081736029formatversion1webaclidar...

358    timestamp1678082486777formatversion1webaclidar...
359    timestamp1678082487818formatversion1webaclidar...
360    timestamp1678082488038formatversion1webaclidar...
361    timestamp1678082490070formatversion1webaclidar...
362    timestamp1678082490070formatversion1webaclidar...
```

I want `timestamp1678081731027` part in every row to be removed from this column at once

I tried
`df['message'] = df['message'].str.replace('timestamp1678081731027', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 2):

If you have always a fixed length like `timestamp1678081731027` (22 characters), you can simply use `str[22:]` to slice the message:

```
df['message2'] = df['message'].str[22:]
print(df)

# Output
                                               message                     message2
0    timestamp1678081731027formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
1    timestamp1678081732769formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
2    timestamp1678081732812formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
3    timestamp1678081732890formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
4    timestamp1678081736029formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
358  timestamp1678082486777formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
359  timestamp1678082487818formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
360  timestamp1678082488038formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
361  timestamp1678082490070formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
362  timestamp1678082490070formatversion1webaclidar...  formatversion1webaclidar...
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use for remove `timestamp` with numbers after it:

```
df['message'] = df['message'].str.replace(r'timestamp\d+', '', regex=True)
```